# How to divide an unsorted list in linear time where every element in the first part is smaller than every element in the second list

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, data-structures, time-complexity

How to divide an unsorted list into two equal parts in linear time, where every element in the first part is smaller than every element in the second part

I tried to use QuickSort but in can result in $O(n^2)$ worst-case time complexity.

Comment: Find median in log or linear time, then in one pass apply the same algorithm as you would to sort a vector of 0s and 1s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [median of medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) with quickselect allows you to find the $k$th element in linear time. Set $k = n/2$ to find the exact median and use it to partition your array in one more linear time step.